# Why do skidding wheels have less traction than non skidding wheels?

Tags: friction

I do not understand in terms of coefficients of friction why this happens? From my understanding the ground and the tire still have the same coefficients of friction right? So why is there less traction when it is stopped then when it is moving?

Comment: Static friction, i.e. when the two objects in contact are not moving against each other, is usually somewhat larger than kinetic friction (at low speed). The surface elements of a rolling tire are static against the ground, while those of the skidding tire are moving. The real problem is, that for a skidding tire the orientation of the tire relative to the surface makes very little difference for the friction forces that are acting on it. In essence, as long as the tire "sticks" to the ground, the driver has control, as soon as it skids, that control is gone.

Comment: @CuriousOne: well yes, but the question is why static friction is higher than dynamic friction i.e. what physics is responsible for its greater magnitude.

Comment: Jack, I've linked a question that is basically the same as yours. The friction for a skidding wheel is given by the dynamic friction coefficient and for a non-skidding wheel by the static friction coefficient. Experimentally we observe that dynamic friction is lower than static friction, but why this should be is a somewhat vexed question. The answers to the question I've linked discuss some of the current theories.